# SQL Select when data changes

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'd like to retrieve an integer value in a SQL Select but only when the data changes, e.g.:

Table data:

```
50 50 50 52 50 30 30 35 30 30 60 65 60 60
```

Now I'd like to get this data:

```
50 52 50 30 35 30 60 65 60
```

Executing a distinct query, this would not work for me because it would retrieve:

```
50 52 30 35 60 65
```

Any ideas?

I'm working with Entity Framework and C#, so suggestions using them would also be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: you need to write cursor for this table

Comment: If you want to do it in SQL you should play around with `ROW_NUMBER` and `OVER`  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<int> list=...;
var result=Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count- 1)
                     .Where(x=> x== list.Count-1 || list[x]!=list[x+1])
                     .Select(x=>list[x]);
```

Answer (score 3):

fetch your results to dbResults then do

```
var results = new List<int>();
foreach (var element in dbResults)
{
    if(!results.Any() || results.Last() != element)
    {
        results.Add(element);
    }
}
```

int results will be list without consecutive duplicates

you can check it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/VpBGnb)

Answer (score 2):

This method is similar in principle to @wudzik's but instead of checking your result list each time, it simply stores the last int in a variable and checks against that instead.

```
var result = new List<int>();
int? previous;
foreach (var number in data)
{
    if(!previous.HasValue || number != previous.Value){
    {
        result.Add(number);
        previous = number;
    }

}
return result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte as (--cte is your test data

SELECT
    1 id,
    50 value UNION SELECT
    2,
    50 UNION SELECT
    3,
    50 UNION SELECT
    4,
    52 UNION SELECT
    5,
    50 UNION SELECT
    6,
    30 UNION SELECT
    7,
    30 UNION SELECT
    8,
    35 UNION SELECT
    9,
    30 UNION SELECT
    10,
    30 UNION SELECT
    11,
    60 UNION SELECT
    12,
    65 UNION SELECT
    13,
    60 UNION SELECT
    14,
    60
),
temp AS --temp numbers the rows
( SELECT
    id,
    value,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rowno
FROM cte
    )
SELECT
    t2.value
FROM temp t1
    INNER JOIN temp t2
        ON t1.rowno = t2.rowno - 1 --join to the next row using rownumber
        AND t1.value <> t2.value   --but only return different values
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me something new